# Can't assign values to a 2d boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, random, boolean, assign

I'm basically just starting with java and am struggling with a very basic porgram.
I have a 2d boolean array that I want to randomly be filled with...you won't guess it... booleans! This is the method I have right now, but it seems that the array is filled with just 'false' after running it.

```
public static void randBoard()  {
    for(boolean[] item : board) {
        for(boolean square : item)  {
            square = Math.random() < .5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you´re just setting the local variable `square` in the `foreach` loop. Use the iteration loop `for(i=0;i<item.length;i++) {.... item[i] = ... }` to access the array and change the values in the array itself. The reason why everything is `false` is that it´s the default value for a `boolean`, and as you never set the `array` values you´ll just be left with everything having default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean maybe something like this?

```
int d1 = 5;
int d2 = 5;
boolean[][] board = new boolean[d1][d2];
for(int i=0; i<d1; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<d2; j++) {
    boolean square = Math.random() < .5;
    board[i][j] = square;
    System.out.print("[" + board[i][j] + "]");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin Esche stated: if you for each loop through the booleans you get value objects, but you want to set it at the reference. This means that the position in the list must be set.

It should work with the following code:

```
public static void randBoard()  {
   Random random = new Random();
   for(int i =0; i<board.length;i++) {
       boolean[] item = board[i];
       for(int j= 0;j<item.length;j++)  {
           item[j]= random.nextBoolean();
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Note that you can use a for each loop for the outer loop; it's just the inner loop which needs to be a "plain old" for loop in order to update the elements.

Comment: I didn't know that for each loops didn't provide a reference, thanks for the help.

Comment: @UncraftedName the variable types with lowercasing (int, float, long, boolean, etc) are primitives. They get copied in these cases.
The variables with the first upper (Integer, Float, Long, Boolean, most classes, etc) are objects and will be passed by reference. This means that your code could also have worked if you used Boolean instead of boolean!